# featured image not showing up with mysql_connect

Tags: database, post-thumbnails, mysql

i noticed a certain problem with the featured image issue, i had everything work nicely until i added a mysql connection to another database to retrieve certain information, the featured image stop showing up, but the post are there, just the featured image.

after i close the connection, i load the page again and notice the place where the featured image should be has an error message

```
Warning: mysql_error(): 21 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1206

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): 21 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 880

Warning: mysql_error(): 21 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1206
```

anyone know how i can solve this issue :( ?

as requested, here's my codes for openconn.php

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "";

$database = "regreg";

$connId = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Cannot connect to server");

$selectDb = mysql_select_db($database,$connId) or die("Cannot connect to database");

?>
```

while for closing the connection, in closeconn.php

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "";

$database = "regreg";

$connId = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Cannot connect to server");

mysql_close($connId);
?>
```

Comment: How have you implemented it? Can you turn on the wordpress debug mode and dump or echo the mysql query? Are you closing the external connection before executing the query to Wordpress database?

Comment: Post the code that creates the new connection and that closes it.

Comment: just edited to include the codes for opening and closing the connection.

i can retrieve whatever i want from my personal database (which is regreg, a separate one from wp)